# Windows phone 7.5 using C# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in appName.dll

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Does anyone know the proper way to cast  itemCollection.GetEnumerator()?

For some reasons, return itemCollection.GetEnumerator(); works fine in windows phone 8, but doesn't work in windows phone 7.5 It asked me to explicity cast it, but I'm not sure what is the proper way. Does anyone know?

```
public class ItemCollection : IEnumerable<Object>
{
    private System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Item> itemCollection = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Item>();

    public IEnumerator<Object> GetEnumerator()
    {
        //return itemCollection.GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator<Object> test = (IEnumerator<Object>)itemCollection.GetEnumerator();

        return test;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(Item item)
    {
        itemCollection.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try this

```
IEnumerator<Object> test = new IEnumerator<Object>(itemCollection.GetEnumerator());
```

Answer (score 0):

also, try this

```
return itemCollection.Cast<object>()
```

Comment: Still can't figured it out. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

hmm it not clear to me why you want to do this: wouldn't it be better to just do this:

```
public class ItemCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Item>
{
}
```